# How to pull out specific key-value from JSON Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am new to JSON and jQuery and am building an AJAX REST API Application.

I need to know how to pull a specific key and its corresponding value from a JSON Array I am getting back from an AJAX POST call.

JSON Array is as below:

```
[
  {
    "empID": 7,
    "deptID": 578,
    "batchID": 38409650,
    "recordID": 1
  }
]
```

Pls help, thanks.

Comment: What is your desired output? Are you trying to access a property of an object in the array or are you trying to find the object with a given property?

Comment: Thanks for responding ... My desired output is I want to have a line of code .... var batchValue.....  and get the value 38409650 into this ---> var batchvalue ...

Comment: @Musa, this question isnt a Duplicate. I checked the link given above. That question talks about array, not JSON array. I tried all that, didnt work. Thanks.